# I am implementing raw h264 player using MediaCodec

Tags: h.264, android-mediacodec

I am implementing raw h264 player.

The following codes work slowly. (There is mutex problems, But ignore it.)

Also bpkt.bytes is sent each frame unit named end frame from other server via tcp.

But mH264Queue is slower for consuming data than filling data to mH264Queue.

The size of mH264Queue is increased forever.

Please see my codes.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RawH264Activity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

//    private static final String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/ksoo.h264"; // + "/video_encoded.263";//"/video_encoded.264";
    private PlayerThread mPlayer = null;
    Handler handler = null;
//    public static byte[] SPS = null;
//    public static byte[] PPS = null;
    Socket mMediaSocket = null;
    BufferedInputStream mMediaSocketIn = null;
    OutputStream mMediaSocketOut = null;
    Thread mSocketTh = null;
    Queue<SocketTool.BinaryPkt> mH264Queue = new LinkedList<SocketTool.BinaryPkt>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(this);
        handler = new Handler();
        sv.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setContentView(sv);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "in surfaceCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        Log.d("DecodeActivity", "in surfaceChanged");
        if (mPlayer == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in surfaceChanged. creating playerthread", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSocketTh = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mMediaSocket = new Socket(CurrentState.get().mRemoteAddress, CurrentState.get().mRemoteMediaPort);
                        mMediaSocketIn = new BufferedInputStream(mMediaSocket.getInputStream());
                        mMediaSocketOut = mMediaSocket.getOutputStream();


                        mPlayer = new PlayerThread(holder.getSurface());
                        mPlayer.start();
                        while(!mSocketTh.isInterrupted()) {
                            SocketTool.BinaryPkt bpkt = SocketTool.readPKTBinary(mMediaSocketIn);
                            mH264Queue.add(bpkt);
                            if(mH264Queue.size() > 2000)
                                break;
                        }
                        try {
                            mMediaSocketIn.close();
                            mMediaSocketOut.close();
                            mMediaSocket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
//                        Log.i("bpkt", "" + bpkt.mCmdType);
//                    }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // 서버 접속 끊기
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
            mSocketTh.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        if (mPlayer != null)
        {
            mPlayer.interrupt();
        }
    }

    private class PlayerThread extends Thread
    {
        //private MediaExtractor extractor;
        private MediaCodec decoder;
        private Surface surface;

        public PlayerThread(Surface surface)
        {
            this.surface = surface;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {

                    try {
                        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType("video/avc");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
//                    Video_format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, interval);
//                    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate);
//                    mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 60);
//                    mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {
//                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00, 0x1F, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0xA8, 0x14, 0x01, 0x6E, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0x80,
//                            (byte)0x80, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x81}));
//                    mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {
//                            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, (byte)0xCE, 0x3C, (byte)0x80 }));
//                    byte[] header_sps  = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, (byte)0x80, 0x0C, (byte)0xE4, 0x40, (byte)0xA0, (byte)0xFD, 0x00, (byte)0xDA, 0x14, 0x26, (byte)0xA0 };
//                    byte[] header_pps = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, (byte)0xCE, 0x38, (byte)0x80 };
//                    mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_sps));
//                    mediaFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(header_pps));

                    decoder.configure(mediaFormat, surface /* surface */, null /* crypto */, 0 /* flags */);

                    if (decoder == null)
                    {
                        Log.e("DecodeActivity", "Can't find video info!");
                        return;
                    }

                    decoder.start();
                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "decoder.start() called");

                    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = decoder.getInputBuffers();
                    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();


                    long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int i = 0;
                    while(!Thread.interrupted())
                    {
                        int inIndex = 0;
                        while ((inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(1)) < 0)
                            ;
                        if (inIndex >= 0)
                        {
                            ByteBuffer buffer = inputBuffers[inIndex];
                            buffer.clear();
                            Log.i("queue", String.valueOf(mH264Queue.size()));
                            SocketTool.BinaryPkt bpkt = mH264Queue.poll();
                            int sampleSize = 0;
                            if (bpkt.bytes == null) {
                                Log.d("DecodeActivity", "InputBuffer BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM");
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sampleSize = bpkt.bytes.length;
                                buffer.clear();
                                buffer.put(bpkt.bytes);
                                decoder.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, sampleSize, 0, 0);
                            }


                            BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
                            int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
                            switch (outIndex)
                            {
                                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED:
                                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED");
                                    outputBuffers = decoder.getOutputBuffers();
                                    break;
                                case MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED:
//                                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "New format " + decoder.getOutputFormat());

                                    break;
                                case MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER:
//                                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "dequeueOutputBuffer timed out!");
                                    try {
                                        sleep(1);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    ByteBuffer outbuffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];

//                                    Log.d("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + outbuffer);
                                    decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
                                    break;
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }

                    decoder.stop();
                    decoder.release();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you only drain the output buffer when input buffer is available.
The fact is the output of mediacodec is often (if not always) not available instantly after queueing the input buffer. 
So instead you should do something like this

```
while(!endReached) {
    // Try drain decoder output first
    BufferInfo info = new BufferInfo();
    int outIndex = decoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 10000);
    switch (outIndex) {
        ...
    }
    // Feed decoder input
    if (inputAvailable) {
        int inIndex = decoder.dequeueInputBuffer(10000);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is meant when you say `drain` the output buffer. I see this term used a lot, but what does it mean? Is draining when you call `encoder.advance();`?

Comment: @HB. draining here means, consuming available output buffer (result) until all result is consumed. This is done by calling dequeueOutputBuffer. If output buffer is full, MediaCodec will not be able to produce new output anymore until the output buffer is properly drained.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you mind having a look at this question I posted about 2 months ago - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50817767/8199772

Comment: Yes, I got it working this morning. Thank you for your time.